# Making Gradient Background in Swift - The Right Way

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer, ibdesignable

This is my code for a gradient background. When I apply it on my view, it hides all my stuff on that VC, like it's on the front and everything else is pushed back. How can I make a gradient view that is not interfering with my elements?

I'm using `@IBDesignable` just to see how is it looking in Storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    var color1 = ColorPalette.GrdTop
    var color2 = ColorPalette.GrdBottom

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureGradient()
    }

    func configureGradient() {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        updateColors()
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.CGColor, color2.CGColor]
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureGradient()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> like it is on the front and everything else is pushed back

Because it *is* on the front. Think about this line of your code:

```
layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

That puts the gradient layer in front of all other sublayers of this layer. Subviews of a view are displayed by sublayers of its layer, so the gradient layer covers this view's current subviews.

You can insert your layer all the way at the back if you like (`insertSublayer:atIndex:`). The elegant solution, though, is to implement [the `layerClass` class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass) for this view to return a CAGradientLayer. Now you won't have to *add* a gradient to your GradientView; instead, your GradientView *is* a gradient and you can just configure that gradient as desired.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, @Kira Arik is also probably going to want to set a mask for the `CAGradientLayer()`

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, but this seems hard to me at this point. I'm still kinda a beginner so... I will probably have to ask someone to help me with this. Thanks anyway.